# How do I authorize a user without a form?

Tags: django

I have a nice user login web page, it has input fields ( tags) for login and password and decorative design elements. There is also a button to enter ( tag).
From the point of view of HTML, this is not a form, because the page does not have the "FORM" tag and the "SUBMIT" button.

How can I sign in for a user without making any changes to the web page? I can process the scripts, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach for solving my problem (do not forget that this is a login page and I will need to pass a password).

I can authorize a user using Django forms (and, as a consequence, a HTML form), but how can I do this without a HTML form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this all the time with my Django apps - its much easier to customize the login, signup pages this way.

You can pass the user information via ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'login_url',
    data : {
        username : 'the_username',
        password : 'the_password',
    },
    success: function(response) {
        // redirect or some other logic for authenticated users
    }
})
```

You can create your own login views or use some of the default Django versions.
You can explore password hashing, brute force throttling, etc. to suite your needs.
Even if you stick with the default Django login HTML forms, you should still have a lot of flexibility as far as design.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need. There is only one question - is it safe to send the password this way?

Comment: Yes of course provided the target URL is HTTPS and under your control.

Comment: How i can recieve this data on django-side?

Comment: you'll need to build your own view function, the data will be available in the request like so: `request.POST['username']`

Comment: I add in 'data' section of JS: "type: "POST"" and in data section "        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'" - and now it works!